# At a loss as to why this simple jQuery AJAX script causes an error in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $('.update').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/reporting_results/mark_result",
     data: "id="+$(this).attr("id")+"&check="+$(this).val()+"&user_id=<?=$user_id?>&product=<?=$this->uri->segment(3)?>",
  });
 return true
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of a trailing comma, right before the end of your $.ajax options:

```
 data: "id="+$(this).attr("id")+"&check="+$(this).val()+"&user_id=<?=$user_id?>&product=<?=$this->uri->segment(3)?>", <-- trailing comma, is why
```

Comment: This drives me nuts on IE. Gets me all the time

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `$.ajax` brackets, the `this` context changes to the ajax action. Can you verify that `this` is pointing to the original element that initiated the click event? I've done stuff like this before, and I remember needing to prefetch variables before entering the `$.ajax` block.

```
$('.update').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = $(this).val();
    var product = '<?=$this->uri->segment(3)?>';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/reporting_results/mark_result",
        data: "id="+id+"&check="+value+"&user_id=<?=$user_id?>&product="+product
    });
});
```

In javascript, the `this` reference can be very tricky at times, since it refers to the current javascript contextual object.